# How do I pull out a stuck facet cartridge adapter?

Tags: plumbing, sink, plastic, stuck, adapter

[image]I have a black adapter for a facet cartridge that is stuck. I’ve tried to pull it out but it doesn’t budge as it’s been a few years since it’s been installed. Any advice on how to get it unstuck?

Ps I live in a remote village and getting it delivered would take 2 1/2 weeks. So I’m trying to see if I can reuse the adapter part for a new cartridge I’m replacing.

Comment: look carefully, there is a retainer clip, it might look like piece of wire, that you have to pull out sideways

Answer (score 0):

You need to bend the brass stem inwards with some needle nosed pliers. Bend two sides in at the same time and pull the black adapter and bend in the other two sides. You'll probably have to do it a few times to get the adapter free of the brass stem that's holding it in place. You might find that a new adapter comes with a new valve stem.